# Class variables in php

Tags: php

For keeping global variables, I am using sessions in PHP, is there any other way to use global variables? Can I use classes?

For example, my class name will be user and with the following variables:

```
user->name
user->surname
user->email
user->permisson1
user->permisson2
```

What is best practice to use complex data variables globally? I want to pass my class variables to all pages in a user's session.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store it in the session if it needs to be in the session, which in this case that seems like an appropriate choice.  An alternative is to use [global variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) though this is more for settings and what not.

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit confused about scope (and so it would appear is the happy mamba).

Global variables are accessible everywhere in a script at runtime. Session variables are values which persist across invocation of scripts by http requests. They don't usually have global scope, but are array members inside the $_SESSION variable which has super-global scope. Super globals are accessible anywhere in the script, but unlikely globals do not need to be explicity declared as global outside of the global scope.

> I want to pass my class variables to all pages in a user's session

Then you need to keep them in the session, and the simplest way to do that is in the $_SESSION super-global.

HOWEVER, in my experience novice programmers always put far too much data of the wrong data in the session. This can then lead to unexpected functional issues and performance problems. As a rule of thumb, be very suspicious of anything which changes value more than once in a session. By all means store information about the user there, the'r prefrences for interacting with the site, but try to find another way to deal with **any** transactional data (including shopping baskets).